# How to make an if/else validation with PHP and Symfony 1.4 form, using Schema.yml

Tags: php, schema

I'm trying to make an if/else validation with my code, but I'm not sure how to do it with symfony 1.4 and PHP. Can you help me with this please?

I'm using Schema.yml to setup a form and I'm looking to link that one with my php code.

Here you have my schema.yml code

```
aplica_formulario_cumplimiento: { 
    phpName: AplicaFormularioCumplimiento, 
    type: BOOLEAN, 
    size: '1', 
    required: false, defaultValue: false 
}
dias_formulario_cumplimiento: { 
    phpName: DiasFormularioCumplimiento, 
    type: INTEGER, 
    size: '2', 
    required: false 
}
porcentaje_formulario_cumplimiento: { 
    phpName: PorcentajeFormularioCumplimiento, 
    type: INTEGER, 
    size: '4', 
    required: false 
}
```

And here you have my PHP code.

```
static function getErrorCumplimiento($remesaid, $Arrayvalores, $Arraycampos,
                                     $monedaId, $dias, $montoEnviado, 
                                     $montoPermitido, $detalle, $codigo, 
                                     $empresaId, $clave, $tipo = 'Monto', 
                                     $compania_id = 1) 
{
    $retorna = 0;
    $compania = 1;
    $Remesa = RemesaQuery::create()->findOneById($remesaid);
    if ($Remesa) {
        $compania = $Remesa->getCompaniaId();
        $companiaQuery = CompaniaQuery::create()->findOneById($compania); 
    }else{
      $companiaQuery = CompaniaQuery::create()->findOneById($compania_id);
    }
    if($companiaQuery){
        $AplicaFormularioCumplimiento = $companiaQuery->getAplicaFormularioCumplimiento();            
        $DiasFormularioCumplimiento = $companiaQuery->getDiasFormularioCumplimiento();
        $PorcentajeFormularioCumplimiento = $companiaQuery->getPorcentajeFormularioCumplimiento();
    }        
    $montoAcumulado = RemesaQuery::SaldoAcumuladoRemesa($Arrayvalores, $Arraycampos, $monedaId, $dias, $compania, $tipo);
    $montoTotal = $montoAcumulado + $montoEnviado;
    if ($montoTotal >= $montoPermitido) {
        $nueva = new BitacoraRemesa();
        $nueva->setRemesaId($remesaid);
        $nueva->setEmpresaId($empresaId);
        $nueva->setClaveRemesa($clave);
        $nueva->setMotivo("Cumplimiento");
        $nueva->setDetalle("$tipo de Cumplimiento excede en " . $detalle);
        $nueva->setFecha(date('Y-m-d'));
        $nueva->setCodigo($codigo);
        $nueva->setBitacoraTipoMovimientoId(3);
        if ($AplicaFormularioCumplimiento = false)
            echo("Imprime monto ");{
        }
        if ($DiasFormularioCumplimiento = 30)
            echo("Imprime Dias ");{
        }
        if ($PorcentajeFormularioCumplimiento = 100)
           echo("Imprime porcentaje que esta pendiente ");{
        }
        $nueva->save();
        $retorna = 1;
    }
    return $retorna;
    print_r("Final");
    die();
}
```

Comment: .....Symfony 1.4? That is out of support since nine years. Have you thought about upgrading to a supported version of Symfony? Also, what exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I was able to figure it out. Currently I'm working with that outdated symfony version, but I'll consider to work with another version or framework. Thank you.